# Download file and set it as background VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to make a program in C++ that will download an image from a web server and set it as the user's Windows desktop background. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string dwnld_URL = "https://i.ibb.co/6wGttLF/Beautiful-Space-3-D-Live-Wallpaper.jpg";
    string savepath = "C:\\tmp\\star-bg.jpg";
    URLDownloadToFile(NULL, dwnld_URL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I get 3 error messages:

```
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"    abcxyz  C:\Users\jprai\source\repos\abcxyz\abcxyz\abcxyz.cpp 11

Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"    abcxyz  C:\Users\jprai\source\repos\abcxyz\abcxyz\abcxyz.cpp 11

Error   C2664   'HRESULT URLDownloadToFileW(LPUNKNOWN,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,DWORD,LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const _Elem *' to 'LPCWSTR' abcxyz  C:\Users\jprai\source\repos\abcxyz\abcxyz\abcxyz.cpp    11
```

What can I do to fix this? I haven't written the code to set it as the desktop wallpaper, by the way.

Comment: No images of error messages please! Post the verbatim text in your question, best using the same formatting as for the code.

Comment: Ok i added them

Comment: Why? Right-clicking on any image, whether in a browser or on your local drive accomplishes the same thing. The only reason I can think of doing this programmatically without user intervention is it being part of malicious software.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass wide strings to `URLDownloadToFile`.  Therefore change this:

```
string dwnld_URL = "https://i.ibb.co/6wGttLF/Beautiful-Space-3-D-Live-Wallpaper.jpg";
string savepath = "C:\\tmp\\star-bg.jpg";
```

to this:

```
wstring dwnld_URL = L"https://i.ibb.co/6wGttLF/Beautiful-Space-3-D-Live-Wallpaper.jpg";
wstring savepath = L"C:\\tmp\\star-bg.jpg";
```

or better yet, just pass the (wide) string constants directly.